# bizarre Facebook connect with authlogic problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authlogic

I set up a Facebook connecе to my application following the http://github.com/holden/authlogic_openid_selector_example. But I have a strange problem with Facebook Connect on Firefox and Google Chrome browsers, it just will not allow me to authenticate. But on Safari it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your development platform accessible to Facebook? In my experience, Chrome and Firefox did not work with that example on my local machine behind a router, but Safari did (just like your experience). However it all worked when the setup was on an internet-accessible box.

Comment: Hey, thank you! It's exactly the same problem. I didn't realize that it could work on production site. However it's ridiculous problem.